# What is the difference between cron and rake task?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I know cron is a job scheduler used to execute the task in background. I am confused with cron and rake task?. Is there any difference between them?

Answer (score 0):

It is as you said, Cron is used as a job scheduler. Etc if you want to regularly update your database with some kind of list, etc ZIP codes. Rake tasks is usually used as a admin tool to run commands in production that can be scripted.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow. 
You use Cron to schedule when a rake task should be executed.
A rake task is a set of instructions that you write in which you can execute like so: `rake add_visitor_to_restaurant`

Answer (score 0):

Think about `cron` as schedule or your timetable where you set in order to remind yourself that you need to do certain tasks (rake task) at what time.

e.g. Do my home work every 9pm, so every 9pm `cron` trigger a `do_homework` task, crone doesn't know what is `do_homework` and what does it do, `cron` only run that task. `do_homework` has a set of flow or instruction to be execute such as check which homework should be done first and how to do it.